# Repeat text box below table at every page

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I repeat a text box below a table in every page?

More specifically, if the table breaks, I have to repeat the same text box below the table at every page and not only in the last page.

I cannot use footer for this implementation because in case the table is only few rows I want to display the text box immediately after the table and not at the bottom of the page.

A sample doc has been [shared](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxuXki7B9n93aWtPbkttZlpyZjQ).

Comment: I think still there is no solution for that:(. All the resources I've found confirm it (http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010588_Repeating_Rows_for_a_Table_Footer.html, https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/192847/how-to-repeat-a-table-row-footer.aspx, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c7e5c24-11b9-4d46-8350-b0f336e25e2a/repeat-as-footer-row-at-bottom-of-each-page?forum=worddev)